# prove that $BC$ is perpendicular to $MN$

Tags: geometry, triangles, analytic-geometry, circles, problem-solving

Given is an acute triangle $ABC$ where $H$ is the intersection of the three altitudes of the triangle. Points $B_1$ and $C_1$ respectively lie on the outer circle of triangle ABC such that $BB_1$ and $CC_1$ are the diameters of the outer circle of triangle $ABC$. Points $D$ and $E$ are the midpoints of sides $AB$ and sides $AC$, respectively. If $DC$ and $BE$ intersect at point $M$, while $B_1D$ and $C_1E$ intersect at point $N$, prove that $BC$ is perpendicular to $MN$.

Is my geometry drawing correct? anyone can help me for this problem solve? Thank you
[image]

Comment: It is difficult to see which points you have labelled as $B_{1}, C_{1}$ etc. Have you tried to label all points mentioned in the question?

Comment: It seems that $D,E$ are wrongly labeled in the picture.

Comment: Point $H$ is defined in the first sentence. I could comment that point $H$ in the diagram should not be on the circumcircle but inside the triangle at the intersection of the three altitudes; however, this is irrelevant because point $H$ and the three altitudes of $ABC$ are not used at all in the rest of the problem. Is there a problem with the transcription of this problem?

Comment: Your drawing is misleading to think that the intersection is H. What is G? where are the other points?